# Is OpenSSL PCKS12 support broken?

Tags: openssl, pkcs#12

I'm running into problems adding PCKS#12 support to client application using OpenSSL in that the type cannot be found though the header is definitely included. Also unable to get example code from OpenSSL to build for the same reason. This could be a problem with opaque structs changes made in OpenSSL, or could be something else (maybe crypto not building with p12 support?). I'm hoping I'm just missing something simple. Note that this is not about the command-line utilities, but about programmatically supporting PKCS#12.

**Context:**

Adding PCKS#12 support to an application that currently uses OpenSSL to support TLS using PEM certificate files. The application works correctly with PEM files, but our cert provider will only provide P12 files. Although we can convert P12 to PEM using a system call to a script, I'd rather avoid that and have the P12 directly supported in my application.

**What I've Tried:**

1. Downloading the latest version and rebuilding.
2. Research OpenSSL issues, docs, and maillist archives.
3. Research Stack Overflow.
4. Moving p12_local.h into an included folder so I can directly use the struct definitions.

**Environment**

```
Platform: Debian Linux
IDE:      Eclipse CDT
OpenSSL version: (from VERSION)
  MAJOR=3
  MINOR=0
  PATCH=0
  PRE_RELEASE_TAG=dev
  BUILD_METADATA=
  RELEASE_DATE=
  SHLIB_VERSION=3
```

**Issues:**

The build reports two classes of issues in build of client application that uses OpenSSL (not in building OpenSSL itself, which seems to work fine). Details are at the end of this post.

1. Error: PKCS12 Undefined.
2. Errors apparently in invoking a macro internally in OpenSSL (I'm not invoking the macros).

**Source**

Adapted from example code at https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/demos/pkcs12/pkread.c:

```
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/pkcs12.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/pkcs12err.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL;
    X509 *cert = NULL;
    STACK_OF(X509) *ca = NULL;
    PKCS12 *p12 = NULL;            << error undefined
    char *name = NULL;
    int i, ret = EXIT_FAILURE;
```

**Types**

PKCS12 is declared in pkcs12.h (which is in my include path) as

```
typedef struct PKCS12_t PKCS12;
```

struct PKSC12_t is defined in p12_local.h, which is only #included in the implementation files in the crypto directory.

**NOTES**

From INSTALL (https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/INSTALL) (emphasis added):

- COMPILING existing applications

  Starting with version 1.1.0, ***OpenSSL hides a number of structures
   that were previously open***.  This includes all internal libssl
   structures and a number of EVP types.  Accessor functions have
   been added to allow controlled access to the structures' data.

  This means that some software needs to be rewritten to adapt to
   the new ways of doing things.  This often amounts to allocating
   an instance of a structure explicitly where you could previously
   allocate them on the stack as automatic variables, and using the
   provided accessor functions where you would previously access a
   structure's field directly.

  Some APIs have changed as well.  However, older APIs have been
   preserved when possible.

**BUILD ERRORS**

Building results in the following 26 errors, all but the last two report as "line 55, external location: 
/usr/local/include/openssl/pkcs12.h C/C++ Problem":

```
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_deep_copy’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_delete_ptr’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_delete’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_dup’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_find_ex’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_find’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_free’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_insert’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_is_sorted’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_new_null’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_new_reserve’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_new’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_num’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_pop_free’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_pop’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_push’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_reserve’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_set_cmp_func’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_set’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_shift’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_sort’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_unshift’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_value’
    invalid storage class for function ‘sk_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_zero’
    make: *** [lib/epri/src/subdir.mk:152: lib/epri/src/openssl.o] Error 1
    Type 'PKCS12' could not be resolved
```

Comment: Compiling your adapted example code via `gcc $(pkg-config --cflags libcrypto) -c main.c` works fine for me. What version of OpenSSL are you using? (You can look for the symbol `OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT` in `/usr/local/include/openssl/opensslv.h`)

Comment: Thanks for testing that. I'll try compiling outside of my IDE to see if I get different results.

Here are the version strings: 

# define OPENSSL_VERSION_STR "3.0.0"
# define OPENSSL_FULL_VERSION_STR "3.0.0-dev"

Comment: FYI, I was testing with 1.1.1d, which is the current “official” OpenSSL release.

Comment: I bet that's the issue. For some reason I thought 3.0.0 was the new release, but I see now it's a dev release. I'll "downgrade" to the latest official version and post an update, though I may not have time to do this until the end of the week. Thanks for the help!